# Assessing programming skills of students under 18 years

Tags: assessment

While there's plenty of existing material and resources to help you decide on the next techie to hire, I could find very little for assessing the skill of children/teenagers at programming. [This](http://resources.kodable.com/public/cs_standards_2017.pdf) is the only proposal that I've found, but it's been created by a private company.

My question regards standards for general knowledge in programming, so there are no specific language requirements - it could be based on pseudo-code.

What high-quality standards are out there?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want to measure how well students have learned material in a class they took together or if you're trying to measure general programming ability/aptitude?

Comment: @EllenSpertus Done.

Comment: Why would it be any different between a 17 year old and a 30 year old? If you can code, you can code.

Comment: So, you are looking for standards and tests?

Comment: @RyanNutt Typically these tests go in the direction of showing your knowledge in a concrete programming language, administering a system and the like.

Comment: @BenI. Correct. One of the problems that we face in the implantation of CS in the school is how to evaluate in an objective way, so there must be standards that we all agree on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four places I would suggest looking if your concern is the K-12 environment:

- [ISTE Standards](https://www.iste.org/standards/standards) (Note: there are standards here for multiple audiences, including students, teachers, and computer science educators)
- [CSTA Standards](https://www.csteachers.org/page/CSTA_Standards)
- [AP CS Principles Course Description](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-computer-science-principles-course-and-exam-description.pdf) (Revised for 2017-18)
- [AP CS A Course Description](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-computer-science-a-course-description.pdf)

These would probably be the best places to start. I suggest working your way from the top down since the standards as listed progress in what I see as an increasing order of complexity/rigor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Peter wrote, the American Computer Science League (ACSL) has wonderful pseudo-code based standards for high-school age students.